# GitLab CI/CD: This job does not have a trace. & No job log

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci, trace, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to GitLab CI/CD's and I wonder what my pipeline is doing. The syntax is correct but the job keeps failing, but I don't know why and would like to check the trace. When viewing the job trace it says 'This job does not have a trace'. The same is happening if I view the job logs. There is just the text 'no job log'.

Every single job I ran has no trace, so I suspect it is a configuration issue in our self-hosted gitlab-runner. I found posts with the same issue but without any solution. I tried to run the gitlab-runner debug mode but its output is of no use.

I am using a shell executor and installed docker on the gitlab-runner.

Edit: I coincidently got a job log once, but rerunning the job gives me the same "no job log" / "This job has no trace".

Comment: I am facing the same for some days. Does anyone know a solution for this?.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html After adding the gitlab-runner to the docker group, shown in the given tutorial, I finally got my first job trace. But I know for a fact that was pure coincidence. After rerunning the same job I once again got the same no job log / job has no trace message.

Comment: @JohnW The issue was that the gitlab runner and gitlab versions were incompatible caused by the migration from gitlab 11.0.2 to 14.0.6. Try to bring the gitlab runner version close to the gitlab version. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that the Gitlab Runner (11.0.2) was incompatible with the GitLab (14.0.6). This happened because we did migrate GitLab to version 14.0.6 but without updating the runner. We solved it by uninstalling the GitLab runner and installing the correct GitLab runner version. I suspect we got no job logs because the GitLab runner couldn't create logs with the GitLab versions being incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it today.
Components:

```
GitLab 13.10.0
GitLab Shell 13.17.0
GitLab Workhorse v13.10.0
GitLab API v4
Ruby 2.7.2p137
Rails 6.0.3.4
PostgreSQL 12.5
Redis 6.0.10

gitlab-runner version:
Version:      14.3.2
Git revision: e0218c92
Git branch:   14-3-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-09-30T16:10:52+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/arm64
```

In /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service file there is a line with the  "--working-directory" "/var/lib/gitlab-runner".
What I've found that this directory didn't existed under /var/lib/.
I've created the directory, gaved access permissions with the following command:

```
chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /var/lib/gitlab-runner
```

and restarted the CI.

PS: GitLab is running in a docker container, what is running on a raspberry-pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04.
Also the gitlab-runner is running on a raspberry-pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

i installed gitlab 16.3 and where as my gitlab-ruuner version was 11.something.
since i was on ubuntu 20 i uninstalled runner by using following commands

**Stop the GitLab Runner service:** `sudo systemctl stop gitlab-runner`

**Remove the GitLab Runner package:** `sudo apt-get remove gitlab-runner`

**To completely remove its configuration files** as well, use the following command:`sudo apt-get purge gitlab-runner`

Optionally, you can also remove the GitLab Runner user:`sudo deluser gitlab-runner`

then  i reinstalled gitlab runner **16.3.0**

to install gitlab runner latest versions i follow this document https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Find GitLab-runner builds folder.

/home/GitLab-runner or other location

chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner builds/